# GRPC Meta for Streaming Flows

Tags: stream, metadata, grpc

Is there any docs/examples describing the session flow for metadata treating regarding Streaming cases. Both for Client/Server side. As well it would be good to understand it both on high concept level and in implementation specifically terms to `golang` / `nodes`?

So in general it is not really clear

- Is it right to understand them similar to HTTP Headers with multipart payload?
- Does `sendMeta` work only once or could it be provided in sequences
- Should all the meta be sent/accepted just before the very first message or could it be client updated/server mutated during the session as well
- On the Interceptors (`nodejs`) level should `start` + `sendMessage` coordinate each other behavior (e.g. should `sendMessage` have any semaphores from `start` in case of delayed `start`  logic to proceed after) or is it all under the hood of client implementation.
- When the call is started from the server point of view is it when the read meta starts/completed or the first received message is the point?

Thank you